# Swagger Jersey project, openapi.json is missing "maximum" and "minimum" etc

Tags: jersey, swagger, openapi

Jersey project using following Swagger Core:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

open and compare "path/openapi.json" and "path/swagger.json", openapi.json is missing information like "maximum" and "minimum". for some reason I have to use openapi.json instead of swagger.json. Please refer to the image below.
[image]

Comment: File a bug report here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues